# Wordpress: depois do redirecionamento os cookies desaparecem

Tags: wordpress

eu fiz um simples redirecionamento com

```
wp_redirect(home_url());
exit();
```

E depois disso os cookies são limpos (a session também), o que não poderia acontecer, como persistir os cookies depois do redirecionamento?
Pelo que vi parece ser o exit() o problema, mas sem ele o direcionamento não acontece.

Obrigada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que eu tinha páginas que estavam como localhost, e outras com o ip local, assim nessas trocas era identificado como diferentes domínios e limpado as variáveis de cookies e sessão. Padronizei as urls para usar todas o mesmo ip ("dominio") e as variáveis persistiram ao navegar pelas páginas.